# How to find size of object in iOS?

Tags: ios, memory-size

I am working on a app in which I have to find size of web service response and response type is id. Please suggest me a suitable answer to fetch size of id object.

Here in this code I have to find the size of value.

```
-(void)getOneTimeWebpayCardsHandler:(id) value
{

YPGetOneTimeWebpayCardsResponse* result = (YPGetOneTimeWebpayCardsResponse*)value;

}
```

Comment: Show some code. Is it data, or decoded data to string / some object? You must know the bounds of what the response is...

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a simple object without any extra internal allocations, this should work:

```
#import <malloc/malloc.h>

NSLog(@"response size: %zd", malloc_size(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

You might check the HTTP headers of the response:

`Content-Type`: The value of this header specifies the MIME type, e.g. `application/json` and possibly additional parameters, like "charset", e.g. `application/json; charset=utf-8` of the response data.

`Content-Length`: The value of this header specifies the length in bytes of the response data.

See also [NSHTTPURLResponse](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSURLResponse](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLResponse) in the original documentation.